# Custom Configuration in .NET - Use element instead of attributes

Tags: configuration, app-config

In all examples I've seen of custom configurations nobody seems to use elements to store data, e.g.

```
<data name="1">
<server>aServer</server>
<ip>anipaddress</ip>
</data>
```

Is this actually possible?

I know I can use attributes like this:

```
<data name="1" server="aServer" ip="anipaddress"/>
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of [ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.deserializeelement.aspx) does not support nodes of type `XmlNodeType.Text` or `XmlNodeType.CDATA` and throws a `ConfigurationErrorsException` with the following error message: `The configuration section cannot contain a CDATA or text element.`

Thus, to store information using the element text content, override the `ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement` method.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do that.

```
<configuration>  
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="pageAppearanceGroup">
            <section 
            name="pageAppearance" 
            type="Samples.AspNet.PageAppearanceSection" 
            allowLocation="true" 
            allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
       </sectionGroup>
     </configSections>

  <pageAppearanceGroup>
    <pageAppearance remoteOnly="true">
      <font name="TimesNewRoman" size="18"/>
      <color background="000000" foreground="FFFFFF"/>
    </pageAppearance>
  </pageAppearanceGroup>
</configuration>
```

Then to access the variables

```
Samples.AspNet.PageAppearanceSection config = (Samples.AspNet.PageAppearanceSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(
        "pageAppearanceGroup/pageAppearance");

    Response.Write("<h2>Settings in the PageAppearance Section:</h2>");
    Response.Write(string.Format("RemoteOnly: {0}<br>", 
        config.RemoteOnly));
etc....
```

Check this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: your example uses attributes, I want to use elements

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however, you can't save data in the method you want and access it through the system.ConfigurationManager.  You can do it fine as I showed in the example above.  Why does it make a difference?

Comment: The only difference is one of aesthetics, i guess, but your answer is not really an answer to my question.
http://manyrootsofallevilrants.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Custom%20Configuration